# Talend Open Data Integration: Read expressions from excel file and then execute them in tMap

Tags: expression, etl, talend, flat-file

I'm quite new to Talend and would like to read an expression from a given file and then execute it in tMap function.

The expressions are stored in a separate excel column like this:

```
row7.value1 + row7.value2 == 0 ? 0 : row7.value1/(row7.value1 + row7.value2)
```

I accomplished to read it as a string by global map:

`((String) globalMap.get("row6.column_that_contains_expr"))`.

But I'm not able to execute the expression in tMap in order to get the resulting value.

My job looks like this:

tFileInputExcel =row6=> tFlowToIerate => tPostgresqlInput =row7=> tMap => tFileOutpuDelimited

Could you please tell me how to execute the expression from file and obtain the resulting double?

Greetings

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would usually do is to have before the tFlowToIerate a tJavaRow Component where I would assign the values into context variables and use them in the tPostgresqlInput  directly from the context

Comment: Sounds good! I'll check it out later and keep you postet about.

Comment: I tried the following in tJavaRow: ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager(); ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); String infix = "row7.value1 + row7.value2 == 0 ? 0 : row7.value1/(row7.value1 + row7.value2)"; context.test = engine.eval(infix); Which leads to an error: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "row7" is not defined in <eval> Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes, When you are clicking in Talend, you are actually Meta progamming. You are saying talend to generate code. What you define in the infix is some Java formula, that you are passing to JavaScript to be interpreted. You can always implement your own classes and methods in Talend that would be able to interpret the formula you get from the file.

Comment: But think if it is really worth the effort